# Blazor Authentication & Authorization

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-roles

I am trying to build a simple app. I have used the Blazor default project and modified it. The thing I want to achieve is that when you log in, the navbar menu to display two more options - Counter and Fetch Data. I have created my own policy and a requirement for it and I have also implemented a custom authentication. But when I go to the login form, type in the user and pass and click submit it only redirects me to the main page and does not display the additional options in the navigation menu. Furthermore, after a few seconds, the page dies with this error - This site can’t be reachedphpoll.com took too long to respond. I want to be able to show the additional options if the user is an admin. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it? I don't want to use the entity framework or any other. I want to build my custom implementations for authentication and authorization. Thank you.
My project can be seen [here](https://github.com/LyubomiRadev/TaskVisionClientBeta).

Comment: I believe the following link will provide valuable tips for your situation https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-policy-based-authorization-with-blazor/

Comment: "I want to build my custom implementations for authentication and authorization" - Please dont. Use something that has been battle tested.